# How can I create lots of similar functions for sysfs attributes?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I have a generic AXI-slave device with several I/O registers in my FPGA. I want to access my registers with a sysfs interface. For each register I want to access, I create a `_show` and a `_store` function, but that would be a lot of code.

```
static ssize_t writereg0_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute                *attr, const char *buf, size_t count) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    u32 val;

    if (kstrtou32(buf, 10, &val) != 0)
        return -EINVAL;

    iowrite32(val, drv->reg_base + WRITE_OFFSET + 0);

    return count;

}

static ssize_t writereg0_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    u32 reg;
    reg = ioread32(drv->reg_base + WRITE_OFFSET + 0);

    return sprintf(buf, "0x%x\n", reg);
}
static DEVICE_ATTR_RW(writereg0);

static ssize_t readreg0_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    u32 reg;
    reg = ioread32(drv->reg_base + 0);

    return sprintf(buf, "0x%x\n", reg);
}
static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(readreg0);
```

The second read-only register is basically the same, except the function name and address offset:

```
static ssize_t readreg1_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    u32 reg;
    reg = ioread32(drv->reg_base + OFF_REG1);

    return sprintf(buf, "0x%x\n", reg);
}
static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(readreg1);
```

When creating e.g. 32 registers, I have to do this 32 times; the code wouldn't be very pretty.

So what's the best way to create a bunch of similar functions, especially for the given sysfs-attribute usecase?

Comment: There's no question here. Can you edit your post to clearly state what you want an answer to? e.g. "How can I generate many similar structures and functions" or something.

Comment: BTW, my reading of the kernel source suggests that its `sprintf()` supports the `#` modifier just like user-space `sprintf()`, so you could simply write `%#x` instead of `0x%x`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you, i didn't knew that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `_show` and `_store` functions don't use `struct device_attribute *attr` parameter, but exactly this parameter is intended for contain information about specific thing represented by a given file:

```c
// Derive 'device_attribute' structure for a read register's attribute
struct dev_axi_read_reg_attribute {
    struct device_attribute attr;
    int reg_offset; // Offset of the register here
};

// Generic 'show' method, suitable for every read register
static ssize_t read_axi_reg_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    // 'attr' is actually of type `struct dev_axi_read_reg_attribute`.
    // See definition of the macro 'AXI_READ_REG_ATTR' below.
    struct dev_axi_read_reg_attribute* axi_read_attr = container_of(attr,
        struct dev_axi_read_reg_attribute, attr);

    u32 reg;
    // Take offset to the register from the attribute
    reg = ioread32(drv->reg_base + axi_read_attr->reg_offset);

    return sprintf(buf, "0x%x\n", reg);
}

// Macro for declare attribute for read register
#define AXI_READ_REG_ATTR(_name, _reg_offset) \
struct dev_axi_read_reg_attribute dev_attr_##_name = \
    { __ATTR(_name,  S_IRUGO, read_axi_reg_show, NULL), _reg_offset }

// Declare as many attributes as you want
static AXI_READ_REG_ATTR(readreg0, OFF_REG0);
static AXI_READ_REG_ATTR(readreg1, OFF_REG1);
// ...

static struct attribute *axi_register_attrs[] = {
    &dev_attr_readreg0.attr.attr,
    &dev_attr_readreg1.attr.attr,
    // ...
    NULL,
};
ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(axi_register);
```

Similar approach is used in `DEVICE_ULONG_ATTR` macro, defined in [include/linux/device.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/device.h#L550). That macro creates an attribute for a variable of type 'long'.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something but wouldn't you just want to make 32 wrappers around:

```
static ssize_t readreg_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf,unsigned long offset) {
    struct axi_register_driver *drv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    u32 reg;
    reg = ioread32(drv->reg_base + offset);

    return sprintf(buf, "0x%x\n", reg);
}
```

and maybe define 32:

```
static ssize_t readreg1_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {readreg_show(dev,attr,buf,OFF_REG1)}
```

(one for each reg) if you need different function names? This might be MACROd, if it really bothers you to copy this 32 times, if the offsets are all OFF_REGi.